# Java - Calcular valor das horas para o responsável por um evento

Tags: java, arraylist

Estou construindo um projeto (sou estudante) em que preciso criar empresa de eventos.

O sistema deve fornecer:

1. o valor gasto com o responsável;
2. o valor total dos gastos com as palestras;
3. o valor total gasto por palestra;
4. os dados do palestrante com o maior e menor valor gasto em sua palestra.

No código abaixo eu criei as classes `Palestra`, `Palestrantes` e `Responsavel`. Estou travado tentando criar alguma forma de retornar o valor total gasto com os responsáveis dos eventos. Criei um `for` para percorrer o `arraylist`, só que não deu certo para calcular. Da forma que fiz ele apenas exibe em tela os valores da hora dos responsáveis, mas não consegui fazer calcular o valor da hora pela quantidade de horas dos eventos.

Alguém me dá uma ajuda?

```
package eventoHSM;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Eventos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Palestra p1 = new Palestra();
        p1.setTitulo("Java Guanabara");
        p1.setCargaHoraria(8);
        p1.setDescricao("Aprenda Java com Orientação objetos nessa série de 30 aulas");
        p1.setHorarioInicio("18h");
        p1.setNomePalestrante("Gustavo Guanabara");
        p1.setNomeResponsavel("Pablo");

        Palestra p2 = new Palestra();
        p2.setTitulo("Python Guanabara");
        p2.setCargaHoraria(16);
        p2.setDescricao("Aprenda Python com Orientação objetos nessa série de 30 aulas");
        p2.setHorarioInicio("20h");
        p2.setNomePalestrante("Gustavo Guanabara"); 
        p2.setNomeResponsavel("Pablo");

        Palestra p3 = new Palestra();
        p3.setTitulo("Aprendendo Libras");
        p3.setCargaHoraria(40);
        p3.setDescricao("Aprenda Libras com quem fala libras");
        p3.setHorarioInicio("20h");
        p3.setNomePalestrante("Ana Claudia");   
        p3.setNomeResponsavel("Ana");

        Palestra p4 = new Palestra();
        p4.setTitulo("Daniel e Apocalipse");
        p4.setCargaHoraria(16);
        p4.setDescricao("Aprenda Daniel e Apocalipse com Felipe Silva");
        p4.setHorarioInicio("20h");
        p4.setNomePalestrante("Felipe Silva");  
        p4.setNomeResponsavel("Ana");
        
        
        Responsavel re1 = new Responsavel();
        re1.setNomeResponsavel("Pablo");
        re1.setNumTelefone("71992092623");
        re1.setValorHora(26);
        
        Responsavel re2 = new Responsavel();
        re2.setNomeResponsavel("Ana");
        re2.setNumTelefone("988599600");
        re2.setValorHora(32);
        
        List<Responsavel> responsaveis = new ArrayList<Responsavel>();
        responsaveis.add(re1);
        responsaveis.add(re2);
        
        
        List<Palestra> palestras = new ArrayList<Palestra>();
        palestras.add(p1);
        palestras.add(p2);
        palestras.add(p3);
        palestras.add(p4);
        

        
        for(int a = 0; a < palestras.size(); a++) {
            //System.out.println(palestras.get(a).getCargaHoraria() + " - " + palestras.get(a).getNomeResponsavel());
            for(int i = 0; i< responsaveis.size(); i++) {
                if(palestras.get(a).getNomeResponsavel() == responsaveis.get(i).getNomeResponsavel() ) {
                    float valorPorResponsavel = 0;
                    valorPorResponsavel = valorPorResponsavel + responsaveis.get(i).getValorHora();
                    
                    System.out.println(valorPorResponsavel);
                }
            }
        }
        
        


    }

}
```

Comment: Posso dar um ideia, não quero fazer a solução pois o caminho é esse mesmo, você precisa tentar e descobrir, mas você poderia ter uma classe de Custos e nessa classe teria um método de atribuição fazendo as devidas somatórias, poderia somar os dados inputados e retornar.

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma variável fora do for para armazenar a soma total dos responsáveis. Dentro do for você faz a conta de quantas horas foram gastas * o valor da hora de cada responsável.
Ex.:

```
float total=0;
for(int a = 0; a < palestras.size(); a++) {
    for(int i = 0; i< responsaveis.size(); i++) {
        if(palestras.get(a).getNomeResponsavel() == responsaveis.get(i).getNomeResponsavel() ) {
                
            total += palestras.getDuracao() * responsaveis(i).getValorHora();
                
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(total);
```

Mas... podemos aqui melhorar e muito o código. Veja só:

- Use objetos do tipo [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) no objeto Palestra para, posteriormente, calcular quanto tempo durou a palestra;
- Converta em minutos, e converta o valor da hora do palestrante em minutos, para assim, ter o valor correto;
- No objeto Palestra, ao invés de definir o nome do palestrante, crie um objeto do tipo Palestrante. Isso vai ajudar lá no for;
- Utilize [foreach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html) para percorrer pelo array;

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma variável para armazenar o valor total de tudo. Uma boa prática também é usar forEach para listas, além de equals para comparar Strings, desse jeito:

```
float valorTotalporHora;
for(Palestra palestra : palestras){
    for(Responsavel responsavel : responsaveis){
        if(palestra.getNomeResponsavel().equals(responsavel.getNomeResponsavel()))
            valorTotalporHora += palestra.getDuracao() * responsavel.getValorHora();
            break;
    }
}
```

Obs: utilizei break para caso faça a operação, ele não precisa checar os demais responsáveis na lista.

O amigo @lelos também deu ótimas dicas de como melhorar seu código!